# Can FK constraints work on several tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints

I have a table called `Order`.  It has a FK to a Table called `OrderSource`, which has a non-unique Id in called SourceId.   `Order` also has a FK to a table called `OrderType` (a catalog of what can be ordered).  It has a PK of OrderTypeId.

I then have another table (`Order_OrderSource`) that limits the kinds of SourceIds I can have for a given OrderTypeId.  (It contains rows of OrderTypeId, SourceId and ClassId (another Id that is used to group specific source and OrderTypes together).

What I would like is to have the database enforce that an Order cannot have a OrderSource.SourceId if it's OrderTypeId does not match up in the `Order_OrderSource` table.

This is kind of an associative table pattern.  But it breaks down because SourceId is not the PK of OrderSource.

Any way I can make SQL Server enforce this constraint?

Comment: Your database structure seems a bit strange. Why's the SourceId not the primary key in the OrderSource table? Should the Order_OrderSource table be replaced with a OrderType_OrderSource table which defines the types for sources which can be ordered? Then you'd have a foreign key from Order to OrderType_OrderSource.

Comment: Mika: I agree completely--that is pretty much what I said in my answer (maybe not very clearly?).

Comment: Actually, that's what Andomar is saying as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, one column can be part of multiple foreign key constraints to different tables.

A foreign key requires a unique index (or primary key) on the columns you are referencing.  In your case, you could satisfy this requirement with a composite primary key on `Order_OrderSource.(OrderSource,OrderType)`.

Example SQL:

```
create table OrderSource (id int primary key)
create table OrderType (id int primary key)
create table Order_OrderSource (OrderSource int, OrderType int, 
    constraint PK_Order_OrderSource primary key (OrderSource,OrderType))
create table [Order] (
    id int, 
    OrderSource int foreign key references OrderSource(id), 
    OrderType int foreign key references OrderType(id), 
    constraint FK_Order_OrderSource 
        foreign key (OrderSource,OrderType) 
        references Order_OrderSource (OrderSource,OrderType))
```

The combination of `(OrderSource, OrderType)` is now limited by rows in `Order_OrderSource`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Order_OrderSource defines valid relationships between OrderType, OrderSource, and Class? And Order is classified by OrderType, OrderSource and (maybe) class?

If that's the case, why not define the valid combinations in Order_OrderSource, and create an FK on Order that relates to this table?  Then you have no need for SourceId or OrderTypeId on Order, and you have full enforcement via FK constraints.

Comment: You could still use an `OrderType` table to store properties of an order type, like expected duration, long description, etc.

Comment: I didn't mean don't have an OrderType table--I meant there is no need for an Order:OrderType relationship, since that relationship would already be implied by Order:Order_OrderSource.

Comment: Actually, after reading your answer, I see we are saying the exact same thing.  :)